# Kindle paperwhite loses the Wifi connection all the time

Tags: kindle, wifi, kindle-paperwhite

I recently purchased an new Amazon Kindle Paperwhite and I wanted to configure the Wifi.

My Wifi router hides the SSID (it is not broadcasted) and I am able to connect the Kindle by entering the SSID by hand.

The problem occurs when I switch off the Kindle, after switching on again, the wifi connection is lost and I have to re-enter the wifi settings.

Is is a known problem, or someone have a trick the Kindle to be able to stay connected after power down?

Comment: Are you completely powering off your Kindle (power button for 7 seconds) or just putting it to sleep?

Comment: @w3d Just press the button, then just putting to sleep. I guess it will not be better if I totally switched off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be a [known issue](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=Tx35REW7MFKG11X) with the Kindle Fire. I'm assuming it is also an issue for your model. I would suggest that you just broadcast your SSID. Most people report this is fixes the issue. If you are not broadcasting it for security reasons, that is what encryption and password are for. If someone wants to break into your network, hiding the SSID is not going to what stops them from getting in. There are many freely available programs that can detect non-broadcasting networks.

Comment: I understand hiding the SSID is not so safe for the real hackers, but it was always my default (WPA-PSK + hidden SSID). Anyway Kindle is the first applicance I found not compatible with this (and I have tried many Wifi appliances like TV, video recorder, printers and phones).

Comment: I accept this answer because I do not have choice: I have to change my network(s) configuration. But a solution from Amazon by updating the firmware would be better.